# get all image from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function checkallfolder(){
  var thumbnailbox = $('#thumbnailbox');
  var foldertype = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6", "img7"];
  for (var c = 0; c < foldertype.length; c++ ){
    var folder = 'Img/dfolder/'+foldertype[c];
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url: "data.php",
      contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      dataType: "json",
      data: "folder="+folder,
      success: function(d) {
        var temp = '';
        thumbnailbox.html('');
        for (var obj in d){
          if (d.hasOwnProperty(obj) && d[obj].hasOwnProperty('src') && d[obj].src !== ''){
            var objname = d[obj].name;
            temp += "<div><img name="+d[obj].name+" class='icon' src="+d[obj].src+"></div>";
            console.log(d[obj].src);
          }
        }
        thumbnailbox.html(temp);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

my intention is to use ajax check all folder inside image , so i loop it with "for" and i checked the con log it do load 7 times and all object are calling out but then i try to output them as "img" with "src". i only get the last img , only folder7/img7 had be show up. what is wrong with my code? all the "src" had been call out , it should be having all image. can anyone help me take a look ?

Comment: Closure!!..move your `var folder = 'Img/dfolder/'+foldertype[c];` outside the loop through a function

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for using closure.

**Problem:**

Variables in JavaScript have function-level scope. Since you are using AJAX (Asynchronous call) inside the loop, your loop will execute no matter the response of the AJAX call. So, by the time AJAX is fired, your loop would have completed and each time your local variable is overwritten and hence, your `c` always points to value set in the last iteration of the loop.

Make `foldertype` a global variable. Move it outside your function:

```
 var foldertype = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6", "img7"];
```

and then inside your `checkallfolder()` do this:

```
...
for (var c = 0; c < foldertype.length; c++ ){
var folder = getImageSrc(c);
...
```

and the add `getImageSrc` like this:

```
function getImageSrc(c){
   return 'Img/dfolder/'+foldertype[c];
}
```

So, in all your code looks like this:

```
var foldertype = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6", "img7"];


function checkallfolder(){
      var thumbnailbox = $('#thumbnailbox');
      for (var c = 0; c < foldertype.length; c++ ){
          var folder = getImageSrc(c);
          $.ajax({
                ...ajax code here...
          });
       }
}

function getImageSrc(c){
   return 'Img/dfolder/'+foldertype[c];
}
```

Comment: @Marcus:  `var folder = 'Img/dfolder/'+foldertype[c];` is causing the problem

Comment: so i just move the folder outside?

Comment: not working too if i move it out it wont count the loop.

Comment: @Hacktor move it outside and add the `getImageSrc`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare an array and push "temp" value to this array and finally 
arr.toString() assign to thumbnailbox.html()

function checkallfolder(){
var thumbnailbox = $('#thumbnailbox');
var foldertype = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6", "img7"];
for (var c = 0; c < foldertype.length; c++ ){
var folder = 'Img/dfolder/'+foldertype[c];
var arr = new Array();
$.ajax({
 type : "POST",
 url: "data.php",
 contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 dataType: "json",
 data: "folder="+folder,
 success: function(d) 
 {
    var temp = '';
    thumbnailbox.html('');
    for (var obj in d){
    if (d.hasOwnProperty(obj) && d[obj].hasOwnProperty('src') && d   
    [obj].src !== '')
        {
            var objname = d[obj].name;
            temp += "<div><img name="+d[obj].name+" class='icon' src="+d
            [obj].src+"></div>";
            arr.push(temp);
            console.log(d[obj].src);
        }
    }
    //thumbnailbox.html(temp);
 }
});
}
thumbnailbox.html(arr.toString().replace(/,/g, ""));
}
```

Comment: the array do show all the image src , but still i can make them show on thumbnailbox.